# What are curly braces after function call for?

Tags: java

In the following code, what does `Type type` mean, and what are the curly brackets are used for?

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
List<String> list = converter.fromJson(jsonStringArray, type );
```

Comment: Type type means its a variable called type of class Type

Comment: Background explanation: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Comment: Insidently if Type type is unclear then everything else in your question is way way ahead

Comment: I've edited the question for some cleanup, but did the "10x" in the original indicate that this is some kind of exam or assignment question (worth 10 points)?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have a feeling OP might have used _10x_ as a short-hand version of _Thanks_. I've seen people use _10q_ for _Thank you_.

Comment: @adarshr Interesting, and Google confirms that usage.  I guess I'll just have to start telling people to get off my lawn, too. Dang whippersnappers.

Answer (score 8):

That's not after a function call, but after a constructor call.  The line

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
```

is creating an instance of an anonymous subclass of `TypeToken`, and then calling its `getType()` method.  You could do the same in two lines:

```
TypeToken<List<String>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){};
Type type = typeToken.getType();
```

The [Java Tutorial **Anonymous Subclasses**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#declaring-anonymous-classes) has more examples of this.  This is a somewhat peculiar usage, since no methods are being overridden, and no instance initialization block is being used.  (See [**Initializing Fields**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more about instance initialization blocks.)

Answer (score 8):

`Type` is a class.

```
new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
}.getType();
```

Is creating an anonymous inner class and invoking `getType()` on the object created.

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets are the anonymous class constructor and are use after a constructor call. Inside you can override or create a method.

Example:

```
    private static class Foo {

    public int baz() {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Foo foo = new Foo() {
        @Override
        public int baz() {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    System.out.println(foo.baz());
}
```

Output:

```
1
```